# When calling CoroutineScope.launch, how is Dispatchers.Default converted to a CoroutineContext?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to understand coroutine scopes and have the following code:

```
launch(Dispatchers.Default) { ... }
```

The signature for `launch` is:

```
public fun CoroutineScope.launch(
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
    start: CoroutineStart = CoroutineStart.DEFAULT,
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit
): Job
```

And the type of `Dispatchers.Default` is:

```
public abstract class CoroutineDispatcher :
    AbstractCoroutineContextElement(ContinuationInterceptor), ContinuationInterceptor
```

Neither `AbstractCoroutineContextElement` or `ContinuationInterceptor` implement `CoroutineContext` so how is the compiler able to coerce `Dispatchers.Default` into a `CoroutineContext` when `launch` is called?

Answer (score 0):

`Dispatchers.Default` is a `CoroutineContext`.

`AbstractCoroutineContextElement` implements `CoroutineContext.Element` which implements `CoroutineContext`.

Put another way, a `CoroutineContext` has a set of `Element`s, and each one is a `CoroutineContext` in its own right.